# Deleted folder shown in folder browser dialog

Tags: c#, activex, folderbrowserdialog

I have a web application in which i have the option to download some files from ftp using an activex control.
When iam changing the user access control settings in control panel from "Never Notify" to any other option, and then download files, the downloaded files are not shown in desktop

Also If i delete the  folder to which i have downloaded from desktop and open folder browser dialog, the deleted folder is shown in folder browser dialog

These issues are not occuring if i open Internet explorer with "run as administrator" option

Thanks in advance,
Sherin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your site to "trusted sites" and disable "Protected mode" for trusted sites.